# Does tinyMCE link list need to be generated by an external file

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm trying to populate a link list in tinyMCE, but the values need to change depending on what the user has inputted in some other form fields.  An array is already getting populated on the page that contains these value so wondered if it's possible to use this instead of populating with the external file like described here:

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:external_link_list_url

EDIT

So is there an alternative to 'external_link_list_url'.  Say for example 'external_link_list_var'

```
tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    external_link_list_url : "myexternallist.js"
});
```

i'd have

```
tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    external_link_list_var : SomeVar
});
```

If not i guess one way to do it would be to pass the values via a query string to a php file.

Answer (score 1):

You may restart the editor instance and set the external_link_list according to your needs.
For correctly shutting down tinymce have a look at some stackoverflow questions regarding tinymce.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response.  Is this just how to deal with refreshing the link list to display the new values +1 for this as that was going to be the next thing I was going to look into.  But what about not using an external file.  I've made some edit to try and highlight a bit clear what i want to do

Comment: there is nothing against an external file, i for myself have never used one

Comment: I don't want to use an external file, but the only info I can seem to find about external_link_list uses a file.